# how to get the maxlength of an input field using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, maxlength

I just wanted to know if we could get the maxlength of an input field from javascript

```
<input type="password" id="password" maxlength="20" >
```

I tried this but it returns undefined

```
console.log(document.getElementById("password").maxlength);
```

Comment: [`.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getAttribute)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("password").maxLength
```

To access it with Javascript you need an uppercase 'L'

[W3 Schools Example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_maxlength.asp)

Comment: Linking to W3 Schools on here is dangerous, it is likely to earn you down votes for an otherwise good answer. See http://www.w3fools.com/ for reasons why.

Comment: Haha okay thanks.  I just figure its good to provide an example?

Comment: Yes it is, no harm in writing one or linking to a fiddle.

Comment: writing one and adding it to your answer is usually the most preferred way to do it here in SO. the fiddle is just there as an alternative to provide a 'working' example..

Answer (score 10):

Use [`DOMElement::getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getAttribute) to obtain properties, that not listed in DOMElement, but existing in markup:

```
var el = document.getElementById("password");
console.log(el.getAttribute('maxlength'));
```